# Criptografia AES128/256 C#.net E SQL 2008/2012

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, criptografia

Saudações,

Alguém tem o conhecimento de alguma implementação da criptografia AES compatível entre o c# e SQL? Desejo criptografar em C# e descriptografar em SQL.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode implementar a biblioteca de criptografia em .NET e instalá-la diretamente no seu serviço MS SQL Server.

Uma vez que o assembly tenha sido devidamente instalado no servidor, suas classes podem ser configuradas e acessadas como no exemplo abaixo:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE teste
AS
EXTERNAL NAME Biblioteca.Classe.MetodoTeste
```

Fonte: ['Deploying CLR Database Objects'](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345099.aspx), MSDN.

Comment: Boa solução, mas não se adapta ao meu caso.... realmente precisava de um algoritmo interno que realize a criptografia. Obrigado de qualquer forma.

Comment: @Pedro eu passei por uma situação similar no passado, e meu maior problema foi a falta de consistência entre as implementacões de algoritmos entre as duas plataformas. A instalação de um CLR foi a maneira encontrada para guarantir que os métodos de encriptação e descriptação seguissem os mesmos parâmetros. De qualquer maneira, boa sorte na sua busca!

Comment: Não há como fazer isso usando as duas plataformas diferentemente. Voce precisa codificar e decodificar os dados "manualmente" pelo C#.